# Python Firebase Admin SDK appears successful but I never receive the notification

Tags: python, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm attempting to use the Python Firebase Admin SDK to send push notifications for my mobile app. I've tested it with the notification composer in the Firebase Console, so I know my device can receive push notifications, but when I try to use the SDK I never receive anything. Nor do I see the notification listed on the Firebase console notification page.

Here's the exact code(minus my personal info) that I'm using to send the notification:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, messaging

token = "registration token"
creds = credentials.Certificate('path/to/cert.json')
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(creds)
msg = messaging.Message(data={'title': 'Test'}, token=token)
print(messaging.send(msg, app=app))
```

This returns a URL that follows the format `/project/<project name>/messages/<message ID>` but that URL doesn't work for me. It will just redirect me to the Firebase console base domain and a blank screen. Also, the notifications should be listed under `/notifications` shouldn't they?

Answer (score 7):

I had had this problem for a week. But it was resolved. Follow these:

1. Make sure your **APNs Certificates** or **APNs Authentication Key** were uploaded in Cloud Messaging settings in [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com)
2. Sure that you use the correct **FCM token** when sending a **firebase.messaging.Message** which included apns (**messaging.APNSConfig**).
3. Check your **AppDelegate.m** file was setup following [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client). In my case, I forgot add `[FIRMessaging messaging].APNSToken = deviceToken;` in function `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`. Keep in mind that the response when you send a message in your server did not say anything about the push notification to your iOS devices even you received a message (it did not contain a notification). And I also don't know how to check whether notification delivered or not.

My python server code:

```
def push_notification():
    title = "Your title"
    message = "Your message"
    ntf_data = {"key": "value"}
    fcm_token = "your_fcm_token"
    topic = "your_topic"

    # apns
    alert = ApsAlert(title = title, body = message)
    aps = messaging.Aps(alert = alert, sound = "default")
    payload = messaging.APNSPayload(aps)

    # message
    msg = messaging.Message(
        notification = messaging.Notification(
            title = title,
            body = message
        ),
        data = ntf_data,
        token = fcm_token,
        topic = topic,
        apns = messaging.APNSConfig(payload = payload)
    )

    # send
    res = messaging.send(msg)
```

And frontend react-native notification listener code:

```
    onNotificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
         console.log("received notification:", notification)
    }
```

Feel free to ask if there is any problem in my answer or if you need more information. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

The return value is a message ID string, and currently it doesn't point to anything (i.e. not a valid URL). It's just the unique ID that FCM has assigned to your notification, and it indicates the notification has been successfully handed off to FCM for delivery. Also, I believe that notifications sent from the SDK do not appear in the Firebase console. You need an actual client (Android, IOS or web) to test this flow end-to-end.

Comment: Thanks, that makes me feel better about the different verbiage, but I do have an iOS app I'm testing on and it's not receiving the notifications, so it's getting lost somewhere before that.