# Python Function Trigger not working in IOS

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, triggers, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am using firestore database

i am writing trigger using python following the link [Python- Trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#functions_firebase_firestore-python)

i created trigger for push notification

i created a function and trigger. it is working in android but not working in IOS

[image: function]

[image: trigger]

my code

```
newtoken=[usertoken]
            message = messaging.MulticastMessage(
                notification=messaging.Notification(
                    title="Push title",
                    body="Push body"),
                tokens=newtoken,
            )  

            respponse = messaging.send_multicast(message)
            print(respponse)
```

Not trigering in IOS

Comment: Do you get an error? have you checked the logs? If so, do you something wrong there?

Comment: @SamuelRomero  not showing any error but IOS didnt showing the notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Solved

Its not code level

after updating APNs key the issue solved.  i got the solution from  below link

[apns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53771076/python-firebase-admin-sdk-appears-successful-but-i-never-receive-the-notificatio)